# Question about a random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

Let $(X_i)_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $\Pr(X_i=1)=1-\Pr(X_i=-1)=p$, and assume that $p<1/2$. Define the random walk $S_i = \sum_{j=1}^iX_i$. Then, is it true to claim that for any even $n\geq4$,
$$
\Pr\left(S_1>0,S_2>0,\ldots,S_{\frac{n}{2}}>0,S_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\leq0,\ldots,S_n\leq0\right)\leq \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Pr\left(S_1\leq0,S_2\leq0,\ldots,S_{\frac{n}{2}-1}\leq0,S_{\frac{n}{2}}>0,S_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\leq0,\ldots,S_n\leq0\right)
$$
The above means that the probability of the random walk being positive up to $i=n/2$ and then negative, is smaller than the probability that the walk is always negative except at $i=n/2$. Intuitively, this seems to be correct becasue $p<1/2$ and thus the walk is drifted to the negative. However, I am not sure how this property can be proven.

Comment: Technically, since both of your events involve the walk changing signs and never vanishing, both probabilities are both zero.

Comment: @Mindlack Right, mistakenly I used $<$ in place of $\leq$.

Comment: There is a clash of indices for $n=2$ on the right hand side. You say $S_1\leq 0$ and $S_{n/2}>0$. So what is the question for $n=2$? It might be false even in that case, and then you have to revise the conjecture.

Comment: Assume that $n\geq4$, only then the question becomes well-defined, as we are looking at even $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=2m$ be the given even number. So we need to understand
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1
&=\Bbb P\left(\
S_0=0,\ 
S_1>0,\ 
S_2>0,\ \ldots,\
S_{m-1}>0,\
S_m>0,\
S_{m+1}\leq0,\
S_{m+2}\leq0,\
\ldots,\ 
S_n\leq0\ \right)
\\
&=\Bbb P\left(\
S_0=0,\ 
S_1>0,\ 
S_2>0,\ 
\dots,\
S_{m-1}>0,\
S_m>0,\
S_{m+1}=0,\
S_{m+2}\leq0,\
\ldots,\ 
S_n\leq0\ \right)
\\
&=\Bbb P\left(\
S_0=0,\ 
S_1>0,\ 
S_2>0,\ 
\dots,\
S_{m-1}>0,\
S_m>0,\
S_{m+1}=0\
\right)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
\cdot{\color{blue}{\Bbb P\left(\ 
T_{m+1}=0,\
T_{m+2}\leq0,\
\ldots,\ 
T_n\leq0\ \right)}}
\\
&\qquad\text{ and}
\\
p_2
&=
\Bbb P
\left(S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
S_2\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}\leq0,\
S_{m}>0,\
S_{m+1}\leq0,\
\ldots,\ 
S_n\leq0\
\right)
\\
&=
\Bbb P
\left(S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
S_2\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}\leq0,\
S_{m}>0,\
S_{m+1}\leq0,\
\ldots,\ 
S_n\leq0\
\right)
\\
&=
\Bbb P
\left(S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
S_2\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}=0,\
S_{m}=1,\
S_{m+1}=0,\
\ldots,\ 
S_n\leq0\
\right)
\\
&=
\Bbb P
\left(S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
S_2\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}=0\
\right)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
\cdot\Bbb P\left(X_{m}=1\right)
\cdot\Bbb P\left(X_{m+1}=-1\right)
\\
&\qquad\qquad
\cdot{\color{blue}{\Bbb P\left(
T_{m+1}=0,\
T_{m+2}\leq 0,\
\ldots,\ 
T_n\leq0\
\right)}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Above, $T$ is "an other similar random walk" starting at time $m+1$.

So we (eliminate the blue factors, and) have to compare the simpler expressions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1'
&=
\Bbb P\left(\
S_0=0,\ 
S_1>0,\ 
S_2>0,\ 
\dots,\
S_{m-1}>0,\
S_m>0,\
S_{m+1}=0\
\right)
\\
&=
\Bbb P\left(\
S_0=0,\ 
S_1=1,\ 
S_2\ge1,\ 
\dots,\
S_{m-1}\ge1,\
S_m=1,\
S_{m+1}=0\
\right)
\\
&=
\Bbb P\left(X_1=1\right)
\Bbb P\left(\
U_1=1,\ 
U_2\ge1,\ 
\dots,\
U_{m-1}\ge1,\
U_m=1 \ \right)
\Bbb P\left(X_{m+1}=-1\right)
\\
&=
\Bbb P\left(\
U_1=1,\ 
U_2\ge1,\ 
\dots,\
U_{m-1}\ge1,\
U_m=1 \ \right)
\cdot pq
\\
&=
\Bbb P\left(\
U'_0=1,\ 
U'_1\ge1,\ 
\dots,\
U'_{m-2}\ge1,\
U'_{m-1}=1 \ \right)
\cdot pq
\\
&=
\Bbb P\left(\
U''_0=0,\ 
U''_1\ge0,\ 
\dots,\
U''_{m-2}\ge0,\
U''_{m-1}=0 \ \right)
\cdot pq
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{ and}
\\
p_2'
&=
\Bbb P
\left(\ 
S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}=0\
\right)\cdot pq\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Above, $U, U', U''$ are "similar random walks".

Now the things can be compared. For each "bridge" $U''$ as above from $0$ to $0$ never going into negatives we have the same number of up's and down's. We revert the time, and the values...

---

**Later edit.**

Let us compare the two probabilities
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Bbb P\left(\
U''_0=0,\ 
U''_1\ge0,\ 
\dots,\
U''_{m-2}\ge0,\
U''_{m-1}=0 \ \right)\ ,
\\
&
\Bbb P
\left(\ S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}=0\
\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
in detail. The $U''$ is given by some random walk based on a similar process $Y$, $U''_n=\sum_{k\le n} Y_k$, as it is the cases with the sum process $S$, based on $X$, i.e. $S_n=\sum_{k\le n} X_k$.

Note first that $m-1$ has to be even, else we cannot land in $0$ again after $m-1$ steps equal to $\pm 1$. I need one more letter, $m-1=2\mu$, say. Consider now all multiindices $a\in\{-1,+1\}^{\times2\mu}$ with $m-1=2\mu$ components.
Among them, let $A$ be the subset of all multiindices $a$ such that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&a_1&&\ge 0\ ,\\
&a_1+a_2&&\ge 0\ ,\\
&a_1+a_2+a_3&&\ge 0\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on. We also impose the condition that the "last" inequality in the list, $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{2\mu}\ge 0$ is in fact an equality. All these $a$ are building a set $A$. For each such $a$ consider the "word", the multiindex $a'$,
obtained by reversing the order, so $a'_1=a_{2\mu}$, $a'_2=a_{2\mu-1}$, and so on. Then we have correspondingly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&a'_1&&\le 0\ ,\\
&a'_1+a'_2&&\le 0\ ,\\
&a'_1+a'_2+a'_3&&\le 0\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on. And finally:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\ \Bbb P\left(\
U''_0=0,\ 
U''_1\ge0,\ 
\dots,\
U''_{m-2}\ge0,\
U''_{m-1}=0 \ \right)
\\
=&\ 
\sum_{a\in A}\Bbb P(\ Y_1=a_1,\ Y_2=a_2,\ Y_3=a_3,\ \dots\ )
\\
=&\ 
\sum_{a\in A}p^\mu q^\mu
\\
=&\ 
\sum_{a\in A}\Bbb P(\ X_1=a'_1,\ X_2=a'_2,\ X_3=a'_3,\ \dots\ )
\\
=&\ 
\Bbb P
\left(\ S_0=0,\
S_1\leq0,\
\ldots,\
S_{m-2}\leq0,\
S_{m-1}=0\
\right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So moreover the equality.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate the end of the answer, and how you deduce the stated inequality.

Comment: Thanks. So the probabilities in question actually equal? I wouldn't guess that.